# Native Query not working properly when inner IN clause returns more than one result

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm stuck with this query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT prfl_acct_root,string_agg(aut_right_type,',' ORDER BY aut_right_type) " +
            "AS aut_right_type FROM (SELECT prf.prfl_acct_root, aut.aut_right_type " +
            "FROM cov_autori aut, cov_profil prf WHERE prf.prfl_tech_idt IN " +
            "(SELECT prf.prfl_tech_idt FROM cov_profil prf WHERE prfl_acct_root LIKE concat(:root,'%')) " +
            "group by prf.prfl_acct_root, aut.aut_right_type) as result group by prfl_acct_root", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Root> findRootByPartialRootString(@Param("root") String root, Pageable pageable);
```

When this returns more than one result:

```
SELECT prf.prfl_tech_idt FROM cov_profil prf WHERE prfl_acct_root LIKE concat(:root,'%')
```

This query sends me :

```
06-02-2020 14:49:51.543 [http-nio-9090-exec-3] WARN   SqlExceptionHelper | SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
06-02-2020 14:49:51.543 [http-nio-9090-exec-3] ERROR  SqlExceptionHelper | ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
  Position : 217
06-02-2020 14:49:51.558 [http-nio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG  TransactionImpl | On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
06-02-2020 14:49:51.564 [http-nio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG  OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor | Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
06-02-2020 14:49:51.564 [http-nio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG  DispatcherServlet | Failed to complete request: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
06-02-2020 14:49:51.564 [http-nio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG  HstsHeaderWriter | Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@7ae3f246
06-02-2020 14:49:51.564 [http-nio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
06-02-2020 14:49:51.567 [http-nio-9090-exec-3] ERROR  [dispatcherServlet] | Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/CashAuthGuiBackend] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root causeorg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
  Position : 217
```

I'm using spring-data-jpa-2.2.4, PostgreSQL 10.4

I have tried many options for the part:

```
LIKE concat(:root,'%')
```

such as:

```
LIKE ?%
LIKE ?1%
LIKE :root%
LIKE CONCATENATE(:root,'%')
```

The query always works when executed directly on the db tool in intellij.

Thank you for your help :)